# c++ threading - which thread will do the work if class function is called

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am a bit lost here.
If a thread1 calls a function which is in class created by thread2 now which thread will do all the work (i mean which thread will process function body) ? i guess thread 2 and thread1 will only get all the output ?

But if a static function is called by thread1 from class created by thread2 now thread1 will be doing all the work with that function ? since it acts like a standalone function ?

Comment: you create objects, not classes.

Answer (score 0):

In all cases (static or not), if `thread1` is the thread that called the function, this thread will do the work. A class instance can be created by a thread and used by any other thread (if it is shared of course).

Comment: @Arnas: don't do premature optimization.